# Bitwise arthmetric Will this result in true or false

Tags: c

Given three variables:

```
int x = rand();
int y = rand(); 
int z = x + y;
```

Is it always true that `z + (~x + 1)` is equal to `y`. Or is there a possible overflow that makes the result not equal to `y`?

Comment: I wasn't aware that + is a bitwise operator. Do you mean `x & y`

Comment: `~x` is the _ones_ complement of `x`. `~x + 1` is the _twos_ complement of `x` (i.e. `-x`). So, `z + (~x + 1)` is `(x + y) + (-x)`, and simplifying: `y`. Overflow doesn't really come into it, because you're not doing any conditionals.

Answer (score 6):

In twos-complement signed arithmetic with wraparound, `(~x + 1)` is equal to `-x`, so `z + (~x + 1)` is equal to `z - x` is equal to `y`, no matter what the original values of `x` and `y` were.

There are two possible reasons why a C implementation might not use twos-complement signed arithmetic with wraparound.

1. The C standard still provides, in principle, for the possibility that the CPU doesn't use a twos-complement representation of negative numbers.  This is  unlikely to be relevant nowadays: the [UNIVAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series) is the only example I know of that's still in production, and I'm actually surprised to discover that it *is* still in production.
2. The C standard says that signed overflow has *undefined behavior*.  That means the compiler is allowed to assume it never happens, and generate code that will produce arbitrarily nonsensical output (or even crash) if either addition overflows.  This *is* likely to be relevant.

You can avoid both of these possibilities by declaring `x`, `y`, and `z` to be `unsigned int` instead of `int`.  Then `y + x + (~x + 1)` is guaranteed to equal `y`.

Comment: “Vanishingly unlikely”→“vanishingly likely.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil don't give me none of that

Comment: @M.M: A Washington, DC, television station once announced “Congress narrowly missed not killing the repeal of the tax cut.” That’s seven negatives! (Not, killing, missed, repeal, cut, tax, and Congress.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil "Vanishingly unlikely" is not a double negative. It means "unlikely to the point of vanishing."

Comment: @zwol: Grammatically in that sentence, “vanishingly” modifies “unlikely,” thus meaning that the unlikeliness vanishes. If you want to say the relevance or the probability of the relevance vanishes, the sentence needs to be restructured or reworded.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, "vanishingly" modifies "unlikely"; no, the modification does not make it have that meaning.  It's an intensifier, not a negator.  But I have reworded the sentence anyway.

Comment: [It has indeed been used as you say.](https://stroppyeditor.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/a-vanishingly-unlikely-peeve/) However, that does not mean it is good for communication.